# An SQL chalenge

Tags: hana-sql-script, amdp

I would like to solve this with pure SQL sentences in an AMDP method, I could solve this easily in ABAP, even in an AMDP method using loops, but as I said, I would like to solve this with SQL sentences, without use any kind of loops.

Please take a look on this image:

[image: Sample]

I have 2 columns, the first I'll name as **D** and the second as **E**

The **D** column, is a result of a SELECT SUM, but the **E** column, is a calculated column, and it should work as follow:

- First line both columns are equal **E1 = D1**
- In the second line, **E2 = E1 + D2**
- In the third line, **E3 = E2 + D3**
- In the forth line, **E4 = E3 + D4**
- And so on.

So that's it. Is it possible to solve this with pure SQL sentences?

Answer (score 0):

Have the SUM in a subquery, then do a select from that subquery along with a row number. Insert that into a temporary table. Then select from that temporary table and do a join to the same table based on the row number, looking for the previous row.

```
SELECT D, ROW_NUMBER() AS ROW_NUM
INTO #TempTable
FROM (SELECT SUM() AS D FROM table) a

SELECT
    t1.D
    ,CASE
        t2.D IS NULL THEN t1.D
        ELSE t2.D + t1.D AS E
FROM #TempTable t1
    LEFT JOIN #TempTable t2 ON t1.ROW_NUM = t2.ROW_NUM + 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but do not work.